# Error: More than one row with the given identifier was found - although tables relationship is 1-to-1

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

From the relationship design point of view, I have a table called **Request** that have list of customer request for changes. Each customer request will have a 1-to-1 relationship with RequestStatus table.

Which mean, each request will have only 1 type of status: Pending, Assigned, Completed. Thus, the 1-to-1 relationship.

In my pojo code, this is my **Request** file:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "requests")
@AuditTable("requests_audit")
public class Request extends Auditable<String> {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String title;

@NotBlank
private String remarks;

private String fileName;

private String fileUrl;

private String fileType;

private Long creatorRefId;

private String requestStatusRef;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
private User user;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "status_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
private RequestStatus status;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
private Department department;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "assigned_user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
private User assignedUser;
```

Then, this is my **RequestStatus** file:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "request_status")
@AuditTable("request_status_audit")
public class RequestStatus {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(length = 100)
private EnumRequestStatus status;

public RequestStatus() {
}

public RequestStatus(EnumRequestStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public EnumRequestStatus getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(EnumRequestStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "status")
private Request request;
```

}

From the data point of view, at **Request table**, for sure there will be possibility of repeating RequestStatus such as:

**Table for Request with sample data:**

| id | title | remarks | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | B | 2 |
| 3 | C | C | 3 |
| 4 | D | D | 1 |

Question:
Sounds like, from data point of view, I should have many to one relationship (from Request to RequestStatus) but, it seems not working.

For this kind of unidirectional relationship, in which RequestStatus is just a "more info" of the given status, should not have any cascading relationship - just a reference. What should I put in terms of the relationship for this kind of cases?

So, Request should have @ManyToOne to RequestStatus? Should I put a @OneToOne relationship at RequestStatus back to Request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which mean, each request will have only 1 type of status: Pending, Assigned, Completed. Thus, the 1-to-1 relationship.

This is not a one-to-one. If the same status, for example `Pending`, can be assigned to multiple requests, it means that one `Request` has only one status but one status is associated to many requests. Therefore this is a many-to-one from the side of the request:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "status_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
private RequestStatus status;
```

If this were a one-to-one, you wouldn't have the same `status_id` multiple times and you could actually use the same id for `Request` and `RequestStatus` (Meaning that you wouldn't need the additional column `status_id`).

Comment: ok thanks. So, to conclude, correct me if i'm wrong, I just need have the ManyToOne as per your code sample in my Request class and then there is no need to have any reference in RequestStatus.

Comment: That's correct. The reference in `RequestStatus` is not required. Check the Hibernate ORM documentation for more details about associations: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations

Comment: ok great. Thanks a lot for the link and clarifications. I be frank, most of my table design for similar case such as Employee can have only 1 Department, is also having OneToOne relationship, in which this case is not correct. I will need to update all for this. Thanks.